# don't get the view for flask wtf

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

Hi I'm learning flask and I try to work on a little thing but I don't get the view for my login page

my principal file (app.py)

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from form import LoginForm

app = Flask(__name__)
#app.config.from_object(Config)
app._static_folder = "/home/morten/Documents/MyWorkK/Work_flask/Environment/forum/templates/static"

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template("pages/index.html")


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    return render_template("pages/login.html", title="Sign In", form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.secret_key = 'super secret key'
    app.config['SESSION_TYPE'] = 'filesystem'

    app.run(debug=True)
```

form.py

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired


class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired])
    password = StringField('Password', validators=[DataRequired])
    remember_me = BooleanField(True)
    submit = SubmitField('Sign In')
```

login.html

```
{% extends 'layouts/default.html' %}

{% block body %}


    <h1>Sign In</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">

        <p>
            {{ form.username.label }}<br>
            {{ form.username(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>
            {{ form.password.label }}<br>
            {{ form.password(size=32) }}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.remember_me() }} {{ form.remember_me.label }}</p>
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
    </form>
```

Nothing appear in my browser for this page I try to look the source page in the browser and of course the code of login.html don't appear.
I'm a starter in flask I do not know what going wrong. Please help
I'm following this tutorial https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are following the project structure like in the tutorial:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")


@app.route('/login')
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    return render_template("login.html", title="Sign In", form=form)
```

The `templates` directory is a default directory in a Flask app.  If you want your templates in `pages` directory like in your original code, you could pass your `Flask` object a `template_folder` parameter.

See the [API docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#application-object) for more info.

Comment: Where is are your templates located? In `/static`? `/pages/`? You need to specify the relative path, not the absolute path of your templates folder to your flask object. Try just putting it in a simple templates directory, and see if that works.  Also post your folder structure, as it seems like you diverted from the tutorial.